# Failed dependency on the installed package in Rocky Linux

Tags: rpm

I'm trying to install a package which fails complaining about unsatisfied dependency

```
rpm -i rpms/semanage/python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.x86_64.rpm
warning: rpms/semanage/python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        audit-libs(x86-64) = 3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8 is needed by python3-audit-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.x86_64
```

However, the package of that version is installed

```
# rpm -qa | grep audit-libs
audit-libs-3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.1.x86_64
```

What am I missing here?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8.1 != 3.0-0.17.20191104git1c2f876.el8

Notice the trailing ".1"